# Button hold on C# application

Tags: c#, xaml, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am building a robot car with a Raspberry Pi 3, using C#. I am able to control it with either a button on the user interface or with a keyboard.

The problem with the buttons is that when I click a button, the function won't stop until I press another button. I either need a way of checking while the button is being clicked or one what checks when the button is unclicked.

I have looked through other posts on button holding, but can't really get anything to work.

In the case of key presses, it works correctly because it stops moving when I stop pressing the button. I just add this to the  in the XAML page. This is due to the KeyUp bit.

```
KeyDown="Background_KeyDown_1" KeyUp="Background_KeyUp_1">
```

This is the C# code.

```
    //Event for when key is pressed
    private void Background_KeyDown_1(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        KeyDirection(e.Key);
    }
    //Event when key is unpressed, emulates 'Enter' which represents stop.
    private void Background_KeyUp_1(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        KeyDirection(Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter);
    }


    //This guy is called when a key is pressed or unpressed.
    public void KeyDirection(Windows.System.VirtualKey vkey)
    { 
        //Detects which key has been pressed, then calls Direction();
        switch (vkey)
        {
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.W:
                Direction("forwards");
                break;
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.A:
                Direction("left");
                break;
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.S:
                Direction("backwards");
                break;
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.D:
                Direction("right");
                break;
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter:
                Direction("stop");
                break;
            default:
                Direction("stop");
                break;
        }
    }
```

As of current, I am unable to find a way of getting this to work. I was hoping someone who has got it to work previously could show me how they did it.

Cheers, Callum :)

Comment: Try using PreviewKeyUp PreviewKeyDown events. I think the problem is that Click event handles the KeyUp event and it never reaches your event handling method.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on the question, when you are talking about buttons do you mean the Control type Button?  Your sample code seems to deal with keyboard keys?